# Is there a way to add an additional thermostat in an office building?

Tags: electrical

We work in an office building with individual offices and an outer office.  Our office windows face East (catching ALL the morning sun) causing the offices to become extremely warm.  The problem is the ONE office that sits adjacent to these other offices catching NO morning sun is the office where the thermostat is installed.

It can be 80 in the outer room and other offices however, it's not that warm in the office with the thermostat so the A/C won't turn on unless we manually force the temperature down.  If there was a thermostat in the outer office will could it recognize the temperature then work automatically keeping the outer office and other interior offices cool?

Hope this makes sense.

Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like you might want multiple zones.

Comment: You could just put one up on the wall that isn't attached to anything. People can adjust the heck out of it and maybe feel like they were able to do something about it...  ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it makes sense, it's probably not possible without MAJOR expense, though it's probably worth some investigating to get a ballpark on just how difficult or expensive it might actually be for your specific case.

If there's one thermostat for the whole floor (or suite of offices) there's probably only one heating/cooling zone for the whole floor (or suite of offices.) Zoning a system that was not set up with zones (smaller areas controlled by individual thermostats) after the fact is rarely easy or cheap.

You could perhaps move the thermostat, but then the office it's in now would be cold...that might be OK if you move the person who likes it coolest in there, and it keeps most of the other folks happier - if your office politics allow for that sort of arrangement.